# Caching youtube videos in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, youtube

I want to develop an iphone app like play tube, where youtube videos once played get cached and can be played again without streaming or having internet access. How can a youtube video be cached in iphone?

Comment: Incase you care... Section 5 of their Terms of Service effectively prohibits doing this. "Caching. Your API Client may employ session-based caching solely of YouTube API results, but You must use commercially reasonable efforts to cause Your API Client to update cached results upon any changes in video metadata. For example, if a video is removed from the YouTube service or made "private" by the video uploader, cached results shall be removed from Your cache. For the avoidance of doubt, Your API Client shall not be designed to cache YouTube audiovisual content."

Comment: @ChrisWagner thanks for the help. But there are lots of apps for caching youtube videos like play tube, how can these videos be cached?